# How to get array and update tableview cell from object that queried with parse local datastore

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

This is my method for query data with parse localDatastore in Swift:

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
 var messageArray:[String] = ["Lope"]
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(currentUser!).continueWithBlock {
        (task) -> AnyObject in
        if let error = task.error {
              // Something went wrong.
            return task;
        }

        else {    // task.result will be your game score
       println(task)
          var results: AnyObject! = task.result
            println(results)
        return task

    }

}
```

My `messageArray` is a list of messages that will show in tableviewCell and I queried the object that contains it along with other things like `objectID` etc.

The problem is I don't know what to do with the object "results" that I queried.
How am I going to get only array of messages from this object and update the tableviewCell to show that messages array in list.

Comment: It seems to return array of PFObject's right.

Comment: I wouldn't do a return in a async call. Instead of printing result, call a method to parse it and in main thread reload your tableview.

Comment: What do you mean by call a method to parse it?

Comment: @sin90 Parse the `results` into the `messageArray `.

Comment: Yeah right but isn't results an array of PFObjects? And how can I get only the message. thanks

Comment: I don't know much about objective c. Can you guide me where to look? Thanks